# Self signed SSL CERT in chrome not working, 2020

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, openssl

I have ubuntu apache2 virtual server on 192.168.75.129 ip
and i'm using windows 7

I've created certificate with `sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/localhost.site.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.site.crt`

and configured it with apache sites.
And added it to windows hosts-file 192.168.75.129 localhost.site

When i go to url with windows chrome it gives SSL error
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
I can then click the address' bar icon and save the cert to my pc

Then I go to chrome setting's and install this cert file to the root certificates, it installs ok and shows in the list, but still dont work!

It gives me the warning!

I also tried to make the cert in ubuntu with "Common name" as my server IP address, but it didn't work any better so now it's localhost.site

Cert in chrome seems okay, only yello warning is in the basic constrains:
Subject Type=CA
Path Length Constraint=None

How to make this work!?

Comment: Well did you try to access it using `localhost.site` or just using the IP?

Comment: Chrome does not look at the Subject for the name - it expects it to be in the Subject Alternate Name extension.

Comment: @garethTheRed: AFAIK, it still does accept Subject CN for certificates issued by locally installed (enterprise) CAs, since those aren't subject to CA/B Forum requirements anyway. (Though it might be that it specifically rejects IP addresses in CN...)

Comment: @user1686 - that _was_ an option on Chrome (up to version 65 I believe).  I don't think it's available on later versions.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a minimal OpenSSL config file which will give you the results you're after:

```
prompt             = no
distinguished_name = req_dn
x509_extensions = x509_ext

[ req_dn ]

commonName             = My Web Service

[ x509_ext ]

subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost.site
DNS.2 = www.localhost.site
IP.1 = 192.168.75.129
```

Create the certificate with:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 365 -keyout localhost.site.key -out localhost.site.crt -config minimal.cnf
```

Add `localhost.site.crt` to your trust store.

Test with

```
openssl s_server -key localhost.site.key -cert localhost.site.crt -www
```

and point your browser at:

```
https://localhost.site:4433
```

Comment: Also worked for me with a regular ol domain name setup in my virtualhost and hosts files.  Just changed the IP.1 to DNS.2 and had both domain.local and www.domain.local listed as domains in the alt_names.  I also changed commonName = www.domain.local, but I don't think that was necessary.

Comment: @StanQuinn - good point.  I added the `DNS.2` option to make it clear how additional domains are configured.